# Can't update filed via CakePHP function

Tags: cakephp, field, updating

I wanted to make function, which after clicking in button will change status of some task to finished.

First of all i have problems with updating filed.

Code of function:

```
public function change_status($id=null){

    if($this->request->is('get')){
       throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    if($this->Task->change_status($id)){    

    $this->Task->id = $id;
    $this->Task->saveField('status', 'Finished');

    }

}
```

Code of button

```
echo ('<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> '.$this->Form->postLink('ChangeStatus', array('action' => 'change_status', $task['Task']['ID']), array('confirm' => 'Are You want to change status of this task?')));
```

And in database theh field Status is a varchar(25) with default "To Do"

The error is

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change_status' at line 1
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You're referencing the `change_status()` function in your `Task` model. Can you show that code? To me, if you removed that `if` statement your function should run correctly with the basic model/field updating calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

```
public function change_status($id=null){

    if($this->request->is('post')){
      $this->Task->id = $id;
      $this->Task->saveField('status', 'Finished');
    }else{
      throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }   
}
```